# Give mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table named products and movedprod. products primary key is foreign key for movedprod table.

This is products table structure
**productid,
userid,
prodname,
manfname**.
In which userid is blank for showing all records for all users

This is movedprod table structure
id
**productid,
userid,
moved_date**

But if any user removes one product for their list that particular product is **copied not moved** to movedprod table with productid and session userid.

So I want select products that are in product table but if this product is in movedproduct table with particular userid & that user is  session userid then this product is not shown to session user id but shown to other userid.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
from product p,
    movedproduct mp
where p.productid = mp.productid
    and p.userid != "sessionid"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN movedproduct mp
    ON p.productid = mp.productid
      AND mp.userid = "sessionid"
WHERE mp.productid IS NULL
```

or alternatively, using **NOT EXISTS**:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM movedproduct mp
    WHERE p.productid = mp.productid
      AND mp.userid = "sessionid"
  )
```

or using **NOT IN**:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
WHERE p.productid NOT IN
  ( SELECT mp.productid
    FROM movedproduct mp
    WHERE mp.userid = "sessionid"
  )
```